# sub-navigation on stacked bootstrap 3 tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

i have created a sub-navigation in bootstrap 3 tabs with a custom style from [here](http://www.bootply.com/74926) and now i want to add a collapsing sub navigation in it such that when the sub navigation opens, it is within the border of the tab, how do i style that? [HERE IS MY WORKING SAMPLE AT BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/tSJiTQelOO)...just click the first navigation and see how it reacts

```
<div style="margin-top:10px;" class="container">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
                             <ul id="myTabSide" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" style="width:100%;">
                                 <li class="active" data-toggle="tab"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseSideSubNav">Nav item</a>


                                        <ul id="collapseSideSubNav" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <li><a href="#0">Nav item again</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#1">One more nav</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#2">Nav item again</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#3">One more nav</a></li>
                                         </ul>

                                 </li>
                                 <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Nav item again</a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">One more nav</a></li>
                             </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: here is another implementation that i havent tried but am too not sure if it will work http://dbtek.github.io/bootstrap-vertical-tabs/demo.html

Comment: My first impression is that if you want it to render inside the tab, put your navigation in the tab body, and don't bother with a collapsible side-nav-tab-thingy.

Comment: See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MSXw4oih09)

Comment: thanks Ted for your reply, i just saw what you mean, but i have other contents to go there...and the side nave can hide if the device width is small

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like the sub navigation to render inside the tab body, put it in the tab body instead of where you have it. See [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/MSXw4oih09).

I moved

```
<ul id="collapseSideSubNav" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <li><a href="#0">Nav item again</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">One more nav</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Nav item again</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">One more nav</a></li>
</ul>
```

inside the tab pane. I used a fresh snippet for the tabs from bootstraps site.

Comment: i want the sub-navigation to be collapsible, like nthis http://www.bootply.com/tSJiTQelOO ...like the way wordpress has their dashboard side navigation, only that i want it implemented with tabs

Comment: please look at this to see what i really mean... http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/McKabue/Templates/blob/master/Edu%20V2/pro.html#Results